# How does this ActionResult overloading work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am pretty new to ASP.NET MVC. And just saw my prof doing that during the lab.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        manager.CreateStudent(student);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. But it's unclear for me how this `[HttpPost]` overloading works?

And what's gonna happen if I will put `[HttpGet]` there ?

Comment: What is the question exactly?  How it knows to choose the `[HttpPost]` version of your method when the HTTP request is in fact a POST?

Comment: I am not getting why do we need the empty Create() Method?

Comment: Oh. The empty `Create` method *is* the GET version of your endpoint.

Comment: The first `Create` action is `[HttpGet]` by default and does not need to be explicitly decorated `[HttpGet]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is a specific implementation of the Model-View-Controller programming model.  This means a Controller method call returns a View which can optionally contain a Model (data of some sort).

In this particular case, `Create` would return a View with no associated model, something like a blank create student page which might have fields like: First name, Last name, email, etc.  Once that data is entered, it is parsed on the client side into a `Student` object and POST'd to the server.  ASP.NET MVC sees the object (and its type) and finds the appropriate overloaded method to call.  In this case, it is a method to actually create the student in some sort of database.

If you were to make a call to `Create(Student)` with `HttpPost`, ASP.NET MVC will return `Create()` since `Create()` is `[HttpGet]` by default.